# Java EE Backing-bean-method not called per PrimeFaces Command

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a strange behaviour when calling methods in a backing-bean via the PrimeFaces p:command-component. The method is not executed, if multiple instances of Chrome running on the same machine are visiting the page, until the other client leaves the page. Same behaviour when trying to open source-code in browser.
The bean is view-scoped and there are really two instances in Wildfly-AS.
The p:command-component executes the bean-method when events are received via p:socket.
Has anyone experienced equal behaviour or a tip to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and do not forget to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, I just have no more details and it's not easy to find a good title for this problem